# Is there an existing eventful COM (Component Object Model) binding for nodeJS

Tags: windows, node.js, com

I have a client who interfaces the IRIS Exchequer accountancy suite via the Windows Component Object Model(COM).  I'm re-writing their existing Exchequer integration layer and would like to replace this with a non-blocking RESTful service in Express.  I've done an npm search and some googles, but cannot seem to find any bindings which will directly interface COM.

Is there such a module out there and, if not, how would one set about implementing such a module?

Comment: I've searched with Ecosia (= MS Bing) for "node.js com component object model" and found this question as top result. The answer provided exactly what I was looking for. I don't understand (and don't want to) why it is "banned" by the Stack Overflow admins. Raf, thanks for the question, jacobq, thanks for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but I was searching for the answer even in 2020. Thankfully, it seems there are more options now. For example, [this article](https://helloacm.com/using-com-object-in-nodejs/) talks about it. It's using this (very old) module: https://github.com/idobatter/node-win32ole

There's another newer one called [`winax`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winax): https://github.com/durs/node-activex

I also stumbled across https://www.npmjs.com/package/activex/ but it appears quite stale and says "Under development. Do not use!"

I haven't actually tried any of these yet, but `winax` looks the most promising.

Comment: finally some light

Comment: Thanks jacobq. Update Jan.2024:
winax last update was end of 2023 - I've now noticed winax, and I'll test the OLEDB / ODBC ActiveX binding, hoping that the 32bit limitation will not be too challenging.

Many years ago there was only win32ole - and it did not work for me. It's stale for 11 years now and I don't see a reason to test it again.